# VPS showing low disk space despite there is nothing major on it

Tags: windows-server-2008, vps

On my VPS server I was trying to see the used disk space and when I open My Computer it shows 17.9 GB free out of 39.8 GB it means that 21.9 GB space is used.

However, when I select all files and folders from C: and try to see the total size, it just count approximately 11 GB. The difference is around 10 GB. Where is this 10 GB going if I have not stored anything else here?

I asked above question from my VPS provider and he responded below

> Check hidden files/system files/etc.
>   This is default windows OS and its
>   utilization and not specific to setup.
>   If you want specifics of usage, you
>   can go ahead and get in touch with
>   Microsoft support team and they'll
>   provide you with exact specification
>   of the same.

I am sure that Windows OS must not be taking up 10 GB space for hidden files and folders. My VPS has Windows Server 2008 R2 installed.

Can anyone help me in this on who is right?

Answer (score 3):

Check and see if you have [shadow copies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd637757.aspx) configured.  Shadow copies allow you to restore previous versions of files in a NTFS file system.  Shadow copies don't show up in the normal file structure, but are taking disk space.  Normally the default is that the shadow copies won't take more than 20% of the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Check the WINSXS folder and ensure it's not responsible for the 'missing' space. More info on that here:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2008/09/17/what-is-the-winsxs-directory-in-windows-2008-and-windows-vista-and-why-is-it-so-large.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For quick and easy disk space analysis I like to use a free tool called WinDirStat which will give you a nice graphical representation of where you space has gone.

Answer (score 0):

as well as windirstat as suggested by bot403, i also use [jdiskreport](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/) for graphical representations of which folders are taking up your space

actually i'd say that 10GB is probably about right for a vanilla Win2008r2 Standard Edition install

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was from the hosting company side, once they were down for few minutes and the problem go rectified, the disc space is showing correctly now.